# Is an NSOperationQueue's thread it's parent's thread or a new one?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, nsoperationqueue

If I instantiate an NSOperationQueue (Listing 1):

```
NSOperationQueue * operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

Then add an operation to it (Listing 2):

```
NSInvocationOperation* anOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithInvocation:theInvocation];
[operationQueue  addOperation:anOperation ];
```

I know that anOperation will be run on the new NSOperationQueue, on a new thread.  And one mechanism to communicate with it would be to call performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

But that's the NSOperation on a queue and thread other than the main ones.  What about the NSOperationQueue object?  As part of the alloc/init does it move to a thread other than the one that created it?    In other words, if the NSOperationQueue alloc/init code (Listing 1) was executed on the main queue and main thread, could I use performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: or do I have to use performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: ?

I haven't been able to track down any info on this, or precisely what NSOperationQueue init does, which is why I'm thinking of writing code to log the various queues and threads that get created/used.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific thread associated with an `NSOperationQueue`. The code of NSOperationQueue runs on whatever thread calls it.

The object itself is thread-safe and can be accessed or manipulated from any thread. From the [`NSOperationQueue` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/):

> ### Multicore Considerations
>
> It is safe to use a single `NSOperationQueue` object from multiple threads without creating additional locks to synchronize access to that object.

Comment: I realize that I am mixing up "queue" with "thread" in an ambiguous manner.  I will re-write my question for clarity.

Comment: From the [`NSOperationQueue` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/): "**Multicore Considerations:** It is safe to use a single `NSOperationQueue` object from multiple threads without creating additional locks to synchronize access to that object." Why do you believe "there has to be a thread associated with the queue, either main or some other"? I can think of no justification for that claim.

Comment: Ken, if there is no thread associated with the code, what, precisely, is executing it?  From the Apple doc "In a non-concurrent application, there is only one thread of execution...By contrast, an application that supports concurrency starts with one thread and adds more as needed to create additional execution paths."    But there is always at least one thread.

Comment: Ken - you correctly pointed out that the NSOperationQueue object can be accessed from any thread.  If you edit your answer to just answer my question removing your opinions about the utility, I will accept the answer, otherwise it's too confusing.

Comment: The code of `NSOperationQueue` runs on whatever thread calls it. There's no need for a persistent association with any particular thread. When you call its methods, its code runs on whatever thread your code is running on. When operations change state, the queue acts in response on whatever thread the operation was running on when it changed its state. (KVO change notifications are delivered on the thread that changed the property.)

Comment: I see your point now.  Agreed, but not really relevant after you pointed out it's thread safety.  I was trying to understand if I had to take thread considerations into account when performing selectors on NSOperationQueue and that answer is no.